# Why did python choose commas over parenthesis in tuple design?

Tags: python, syntax, tuples, language-lawyer, language-design

From [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax)

> **Multiple Element Tuples**
>
> In Python, multiple-element tuples look like:
>
> `1,2,3`
>
> ...
>
> but again, it is the commas, not the parentheses, that define the tuple.

Oh, really?!

Then why:

```
>>> tuple((((((1, 2, 3)))))) # creates a valid tuple
# (1, 2, 3)
>>> tuple(1, 2, 3, ) # But not here
# TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

More seriously, I don't get why the parenthesis was not chosen over the commas?

Because I think it would create a paradox when:

```
>>> 1, # is a valid tuple
# (1,)
>>> tuple([1]) # Or this
# (1,)
>>> tuple(1) # But not this one
# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

However, if you consider that parenthesis were **always** in charge of instantiating  a `tuple`, all of the problems with instantiating  `tuple` with multiple items are gone.

e.g. in my imaginary world:

```
>>> (1, 2, 3) # stay valid
# (1, 2, 3)
>>> (1) # is newly valid
# (1)
>>> () # stay valid
# ()
>>> 1, 
# TypeError: int() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I know this is a well-known feature and I'm already sorry if it a duplicate. I have found lots of similar topics about how tuple worked, but none explaining in details why this feature was created like that.

I am also aware that this topic could be closed as opinion-based, but I am mostly interested in *technical reasons* (if any), or at least *historical reasons*.

Thank you

Comment: This only "creates a paradox" if you assume that tuple literals work the same way as the `tuple` function, but `tuple` **doesn't work the same way as tuple literals**. A tuple literal, can be thought of as saying "make a tuple with the elements a and b and c": `a,b,c`. The `tuple` function takes *any iterable as an argument* and creates a tuple *from the elements in the iterable.*

Comment: Furthermore, there are cases where a parenthesis *are required*, e.g. if you want to pass a tuple as an argument to a function.

Comment: So you want `2 * (3 + 4)` to result in the tuple `(7, 7)` instead of the number `14`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I agree, but in this case, why parenthesis are not **always** required? `1, ` will automatically be casted into `tuple` for no reasons whatsoever.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, very good point actually...

Comment: It isn't being "casted". *That is a tuple literal*.  They aren't always required because there is no reason for them to *be* required, and it looks quite nice when you can leave out parenthesis, e.g. `return a, b` instead of `return (a, b)`. But more importantly, do you see why this doesn't create a "paradox"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, it could also create confusion if you write `return a,` instead of `return (a, )` but I also see your point

Comment: What would be the confusion?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if while reading the code again you did not saw the `,` and expect an `int ` instead of a `tuple`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an artifact of the [grammar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Grammar/Grammar).

The terms separated by commas are a building block for tuples, lists, and sets depending on whether they are wrapped by square brackets, curly braces, or nothing at all.

The chief challenge when specifying a grammar is balancing multiple competing uses of the same characters.  Commas separate parts of lists, tuples, dicts, and sets.  Commas also separate arguments in function calls.  Trailing commas are allowed for both uses (and are required for tuples of length one). Likewise, parentheses have multiple uses including function calls and grouping for arithmetic expressions.  The period serves as a decimal point and for the getattribute operator.

Comment: That's true, both parentheses and commas have multiple uses. Thanks for the link. And  I'm sorry if the question sounded arrogant.

Comment: @MaxChrétien I thought it was a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `tuple(..)` does *not* take multiple arguments, is because there can be confusion between (1) a single element with an iterable that should be converted to a tuple, and (2) multiple arguments.

Say you call tuple with a single iterable element, then there can be confusion whether Python should construct a tuple with *one* element: the iterable; or a tuple that is constructed based on the given iterable. The designers of Python chose the latter. As is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple):

> **`tuple(iterable)`**

This is reasonable since then one can write:

```
tuple(x*x for x in somelist if x%2)
```

For instance to construct a tuple with squares of odd elements of the `somelist`.

In your first example:

```
tuple((((((1, 2, 3))))))
```

You have constructed a tuple `(1, 2, 3)`. Now you pass that tuple to the tuple constructor as the only parameter. Since a tuple is an iterable, you thus construct a tuple based on the only iterable you pass.

Your expression:

```
tuple(1, 2, 3, )
```

However raises an error, since you provide more elements than the only one that you *can* and *should* pass.

Next you have the *tuple **literal***. A literal is a comma separated list of expressions. It constructs a tuple with the given elements. In case you would however call a method without additional parenthesis, there is confusion between (1) a tuple literal; and (2) multiple arguments you pass to the method.

There are other such "grammar" aspects in Python. For instance if you pass a generator to a function with multiple arguments, the generator needs to be enclosed by parenthesis as well.

Comment: Thanks for providing extra examples.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, parens do not serve anything more than grouping, but when they appear after a callable, they have a different connotation than just grouping expressions; Python unlike, say Haskell, requires those parens to make the call.

In the following example, the outer pair of parens are bound to the function call (language construct), while the nested ones group the inner expression (the function arguments(s)) as a tuple:

```
>>> tuple((1, 2, 3))
(1, 2, 3)
```

Essentially, the tuple is created by the comma(s).